# Балансировка бинарного дерева поиска

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево, балансировка

Доброго времени суток. Есть бинарное дерево поиска. Нужно его сбалансировать, но не получается из дерева сделать массив объектов. По-идее, должно быть как-то так, но почему-то не все элементы попадают в массив.

```
void GetMassive(int &n, tree_node * root, DataM *M)
{
    if (root!=NULL)
    {
        GetMassive(n,root->left,M);
        M[n++] = root->info;
        GetMassive(n,root->right,M);
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется вместо `while` должен быть `if`

Comment: А ещё желательно либо `int n` сделать глобальной переменной, либо заменить `int n` на `int &n`

Comment: Вся проблема в этом и была. Передавать надо было через указатель..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде есть две проблемы.

1. `while (root!=NULL)`. Если код зайдёт внутрь этого цикла, то он из него уже не выйдет, потому что значение переменной `root` не меняется внутри цикла. Нужно заменить `while` на `if`.
2. Параметр функции `int n`. Рассмотрим самый первый вызов функции, `n == 0`. Далее выполняется строчка `GetMassive(n,root->left,M);`. Если левое поддерево не пусто, то первые несколько элементов массива `M` заполнятся. Но в самом первом вызове функции по прежнему `n == 0`. Поэтому элемент `M[0]` перезапишется. Нужно либо `n` сделать глобальной переменной, либо заменить `int n` на `int &n`.

Возможное решение:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int DataM;

struct tree_node {
    DataM info;
    tree_node *left = nullptr;
    tree_node *right = nullptr;

    tree_node(DataM info) : info(info) {}
};

void GetMassive(tree_node *root, DataM *M, int &n) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        GetMassive(root->left, M, n);
        M[n++] = root->info;
        GetMassive(root->right, M, n);
    }
}

void GetMassive(tree_node *root, DataM *M) {
    int n = 0;
    GetMassive(root, M, n);
}

int main() {
    tree_node *left = new tree_node(1);
    tree_node *right = new tree_node(4);
    tree_node *right_left = new tree_node(3);
    tree_node *right_right = new tree_node(5);
    tree_node *root = new tree_node(2);

    right->left = right_left;
    right->right = right_right;
    root->left = left;
    root->right = right;

    DataM array[5];
    GetMassive(root, array);
    for (int array_i : array) {
        std::cout << array_i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, я по наводке  выше исправил :) Спасибо.